# how to Trigger componentWillReceiveProps on React-storybook

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to test my UI component on React Storybook ([link](https://github.com/kadirahq/react-storybook/blob/master/docs/writing_stories.md)). However, I will like to add a button so when I pressed it, it will pass a new props to the component that is already rendered, (hence trigger the lifecycle method componentWillReceiveProps). However, I don't know how to do that. I will really appreciate any helps on this, thank you.

Comment: Now there is an addon for changing story props. See [knobs](https://github.com/kadirahq/storybook-addon-knobs).

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the first shared parent of the button and the component that you're trying to trigger `componentWillReceiveProps` for.

For instance, suppose your structure looks like this:

```js
<SomeComponent>
  <AnotherComponent someProp={someValue} />
  <AThirdComponent>
    <button />
  </AThirdComponent>
</SomeComponent>
```

`SomeComponent` is the first shared parent of `AnotherComponent` and the `button`.

Once you've found your shared parent, add some state and a method to it:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateButton = this.updateButton.bind(this);
    this.state = { buttonWasClicked: false };
  }

  updateButton() {
    this.setState({ buttonWasClicked: true});
  }
}
```

Now pass the `updateButton` method down to your button in `AThirdComponent` and attach the state to `AnotherComponent`:

```js
render() { // SomeComponent's render method
  return (
    <div>
      <AnotherComponent buttonWasClicked={this.state.buttonWasClicked} />
      <AThirdComponent updateButton={this.updateButton}`/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And in `AThirdComponent`, attach the updateButton handler to the button:
`<button onClick={this.props.updateButton} />`

Now when you click the button, `SomeComponent`'s state will update, causing it to pass new props to `AnotherComponent`.